# Add target="_blank" to the anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I add target="_default" to the anchor tag in this code below? I want to open all of the link in new window

```
function() {  
     $('.status_success>a').each(function(i,e){ 
    var eVal = $(e).text(); 
    if (eVal == "Success"){ 
       e.click(); 
    } 
 }); }
```

Thank you j08691 for the code. I realized that what I need is blank, not default to open all the links in new tab.

Here is the fixed code:

```
function () {
$('.status_success>a').each(function (i, e) {
    var eVal = $(e).text();
    $("*").attr('target', '_blank');
    if (eVal == "Success") {
        e.click();
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just add it to the `a` element when you create it?

Comment: what do you want to do? there's no such `_default` target...

Comment: Anyway, you cannot open more than one link at once without explicitely allowing it regarding browser popup blocker

Comment: @h2oooooo: I am an end-users

Comment: @BhojendraNepal  sorry I am not quite master the html basic yet, but I am learning new things everyday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `$(this).attr('target', '_default')`:

```
function () {
    $('.status_success>a').each(function (i, e) {
        var eVal = $(e).text();
        $(this).attr('target', '_default');
        if (eVal == "Success") {
            e.click();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is there a `_default` target?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal [According to MDN; no](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target). [According to the HTML specification; depends (but in this context, most likely no)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword).

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to fix my code. Man, this place has become a non-newbie,only master community

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - (virtually) Any string is valid, although there are some with special meanings. The OP may be looking for `_blank`, however `_default` is valid.